# How to add timestamp to my filePath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, timestamp, download

I have a static file path to a download folder, files download fine but when I download a new one the old one gets replaced by new. I suppose because of static pathing. How do I add a timestamp to my code so whenever a new download is made the old one wouldn't get replaced?Or maybe even give download file the "original" filename from the actual array?

here is my download code:

```
-(void) Savefile {

    [self.downloadfile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (error)  {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wooopss!" message:@"Download failed. Try Again..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else if (data) {


            [data writeToFile:@"/Users/Danny/Desktop/PDFFile/hello.pdf" atomically:NO ];



            NSLog(@"Downloading file...");

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Downloading" message:@"File is being downloaded..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddYYYYmmss"];

NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/Danny/Desktop/PDFFile/hello_%@.pdf", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
```

Which will give you this:

```
/Users/Danny/Desktop/PDFFile/hello_032620144401.pdf
```

Not entirely sure what you mean by:

> Or maybe even give download file the "original" filename from the
>   actual array

Comment: Thanks ill try it. Oh what i meant by that is original file name as in the name given to the file within the database on my Parse. I am saving these files from there.

Comment: comes up with "no known class for selector string from date"

Comment: Got it working! Thanks a lot man Ive been stuck on this for a while. Still new to all this stuff